# What is this asking? Let  = {(1,1), (2,1), (3,2), (4,3)}. Use the definition above to find   ,  = 2, 3, 4, ….

Tags: discrete-mathematics, relations

I'm having trouble as to seeing what this problem is asking. Am I supposed to create an algorithm that'll find $R^n$ for set R? If I'm just supposed to find $R^n$ for $R$, why does $n$ continue off into infinity?

**Definition:**
Let $R$ be a relation on the set $A$. The powers $^$, $ = 1, 2, 3, \dots$ are defined recursively by
$^1 = $ and $^{+1} = ^ \circ $.
The definition shows that $^2 =  \circ $, $^3 = R^2 \circ  = ( \circ ) \circ $ and so on.

Let $ = \{(1,1), (2,1), (3,2), (4,3)\}$. Use the definition above to find $^$, $ = 2, 3, 4, \ldots$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Compute $R^2$ first. You have $1\to1,$ $2\to 1,$ $3\to 2$ and $4\to 3,$ so composing this with itself, $R^2 = \{(1,1),(2,1),(3,1),(4,2)\}.$ Now do it again, You see how this is going to go?

Comment: If it's maybe confusing cause of the relation thing, keep in mind that this relation happens to be a function, so this is just function composition.

Comment: So what I'm seeing is that it will eventually reach {(1,1), (2,1), (3,1), (4,1)}, does it end there since the outputs are all 1?

Comment: Well, $R^n$ keeps being defined but yeah, for $n\ge 3$ it's always that.

Comment: Ah that makes sense now. I appreciate the help @spaceisdarkgreen !

Comment: @bobozoid If spaceisdarkgreen answered your question you should probably mark it as accepted (select the green checkmark).

Answer (score 0):

I think you are asking ``How am I supposed to solve an infinite number of problems?''

Without solving it for you, note that there are a finite number of relations over a finite set, so at some point $R^n$ must repeat itself with a fixed period (maybe even becoming a constant). Have you tried to solve it for some small values?